# extract text from html link with VBA

Tags: html, vba, hyperlink, extract

I'm using VBA to extract from a web page that has multiple unordered list entries like this:

2015/16 ICD-10-CM S82.311D Torus fracture of lower end of right tibia, subsequent encounter for fracture with routine healing
or:

I am able to get the "ICD-10-CM S82.311D" value, but I need the "Torus fracture..." values to the right of the link. How do I do this?

Here's my code:

Public Function convertICD(ByVal icdCode As String)

```
Dim ie As Variant
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = False
ie.navigate "www.icd10data.com/Convert/" & icdCode
Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until ie.ReadyState = 4
Dim DOC As HTMLDocument
Set DOC = ie.Document
Dim idx As Integer
Dim answer As String
answer = ""
Dim links As Variant
Dim lnk As Variant
Dim cnt As Integer
cnt = 0
Set links = DOC.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each lnk In links
    cnt = cnt + 1
    If cnt > 8 Then    'Ignore the first 8
        answer = answer + lnk.innerText + vbCrLf
    End If
Next
convertICD = answer
Set ie = Nothing
```

End Function

Comment: I'm sure a groan will go up from the people that know best how to do this, but in case you get no other responses... you could search the webpage text for a string like 'converts approximately to' (or some string that will ALWAYS be returned) then go to the 8th '>' and the string you seek will start with the 8th +1 and go to the next '<' - 1.

Comment: getElementsByClassName("img externalIcon") might work too

Comment: Thanks guys. Dug into the "view source" and tried getting by TagName "li". Getting the innerText of that gave me my code and the detail, and then I just had to parse them out. There might be a better way, but this suffices for my needs. Again, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing DOC.getElementsByTagName("li"), ignoring the first 7 and then processing the lnk.innerText of the rest got me what I needed. The code and the detail were in the innerText and I just had to parse it. Consider this closed, though I'd be happy to see a more elegant solution.

Comment: This worked very well. I was able to xref all ICD 10 codes to their appropriate ICD 9 values. There might be a better way, but it did the 70K lookups in a timely enough basis that my coworker was able to make a presentation today.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all that information much more quickly using a browserless XHR request and selecting by classname and index. I have put one ICD code in the array ICDs. You can extend this.

---

**Page view:**

[image: page view]

---

**Code output:**

[image: Code output]

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim sResponse As String, HTML As New HTMLDocument
    Const BASE_URL As String = "https://www.icd10data.com/Convert/"
    Dim ICDs(), currICD As Long
    ICDs = Array("S92.311D")

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        For currICD = LBound(ICDs) To UBound(ICDs)
            .Open "GET", BASE_URL & ICDs(currICD), False
            .send
            sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
            sResponse = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))

            With HTML
                .body.innerHTML = sResponse
                Debug.Print .getElementsByClassName("pageHeading")(0).innerText
                Debug.Print .getElementsByClassName("contentBlurbConversion")(0).innerText
            End With
        Next currICD
    End With
End Sub
```